# simple aws-sdk-mock times out without calling callback

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, amazon-web-services

I am currently writing some unit tests in nodejs using the [mocha](http://unitjs.com/guide/mocha.html) framework. Recently, I've been trying to learn how to mock the Amazon Web Services SDK, using the [aws-sdk-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-mock) module and the explanations on the same page.
I have come up with a short test which is supposed to mock the DynamoDB DocumentClient 'get' operation, call it once, and log the return value. Here is the code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var AwsMock = require('aws-sdk-mock');
describe("xyz", function() {
    it('should call "get" on mock database', function(done) {
        AwsMock.mock('DynamoDB.DocumentClient', 'get', function(params, callback) {
            callback(null, {
                Item: {
                    Key: 'Value'
                }
            });
        });
        var dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
        dynamoDb.get({}, function(err, data) {
            console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

However, for some reason that is escaping me, this test keeps failing with a timeout error, as the callback error is seemingly never called. This is the full test result:

```
xyz
    1) should call "get" on mock database

  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) xyz should call "get" on mock database:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I believe I followed the explanations on the aws-sdk-mock page pretty closely (I copied the mock part without changes), and I cannot find the fault in this code. I searched google and Stackoverflow, but couldn't find a similar question, so  **can anyone tell me where the  problem is?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure if this help anyone, but had similar problem; had to setup my [aws-cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) with my account key and secret key.

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I ended up moving to a different project.